# Open new Tab or browser tab on click in flex 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I am new in Flex. I have a Advance data-grid. I click on column in advance data-grid, stage1 get open with filled data using WSDL. I want to open stage1 in new tab or new browser tab with filled data using WSDL. like that if i click on 10 times on Advance data-grid column, 10 new tab should open with filled data using WSDL. 
Please help me.

Comment: You cannot do what you are looking but there is workaround to do, use localconnection to achieve what you are looking for. FYR: - http://www.stevekamerman.com/2008/06/bidirectional-localconnections-in-actionscript-3-flex-2-flex-3-flash-cs3/

Answer (score 5):

New tab    `navigateToURL(newLink,"_blank");`

Same tab   `navigateToURL(newLink,"_self");`

Answer (score 0):

You can do with ExternalInterface and Javascript. Put your swf in a html page and call the javascript function to open the new window. In the new window you can open your swf with the stage1.

Please refer the following link.

http://www.riafox.com/2008/09/open-new-browser-in-window/

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(*url*);
navigateToURL(urlRequest, "_blank"); //blank will open the link in a new tab
```